# MVC div Bootstrap Collapse Button to Dynamic Data

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Working on an MVC WebApp project and would like to have a button be a "manager" but also show dynamic data about the "employees" they manage through a cascading effect using bootstraps collapse data-toggle. So far I have been unsuccessful.

Take a look at my diagram [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHMoc.png), to see what I am looking to achieve.

Basically how do I use a button to display dynamic data using div instead of table.

Here is a quick example of what I have started:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    @foreach (var man in Model.Manager)
    { //this loop displays all the Manager names
        <div class="col-md-4">
            //@*@Html.ActionLink(man.ManagerName, "Index", new { id = man.ManagerID }, new { @class = "btn btn-sm", data_toggle = "collapse", data_target = "#employee" })*@ <!-- This is the cshtml that doesnt work. -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#employee">@man.ManagerName</button>
            <div id="employee" class="collapse">
                <div class="row"> //This throws everything off
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                            @foreach (var emp in man.Employee)
                            {

                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => emp.EmployeeName)

                            }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = man.ManagerID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = man.ManagerID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
        </div>
    }
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post explains how to fix the alignment problem and problem with the collapse.  Every row will be class = collapse and will collapse/expand only first row.  Everything works.

```
<div class="container">
    @{int i = 0;}
    @*<div class="row">*@
        @foreach (var man in Model.Manager)
        { //this loop displays all the Manager names

            //MOVING This in here fixes your problem with alignment
            <div class="row">

            @{i++;}

            <div class="col-md-4">
                //@*@Html.ActionLink(man.ManagerName, "Index", new { id = man.ManagerID }, new { @class = "btn btn-sm", data_toggle = "collapse", data_target = "#@i" })*@ <!-- This is the cshtml that doesnt work. -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@i">@man.ManagerName</button>
                <div id="@i" class="collapse">
                    <div class="row">
                        //This throws everything off
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @foreach (var emp in man.Employee)
                            {

                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => emp.EmployeeName)

                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = man.ManagerID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = man.ManagerID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            </div>

            @*//MOVING This in here fixes your problem with alignment*@
            </div>     

        }
    @*</div>*@
</div>
```